# confused in selecting Check and Unchecked in Percent Executions-Per User

Tags: jmeter

I am little confused in selecting Check and Unchecked in Percent Executions-Per User.

Below is the Original Test Design in terms of Users using HP tool.

[image]

I have designed the above TestDesign d as below using SteppingThread Group and Throughput Controller

Under Stepping Thread Group it has 9 Scenarios. Used Throughput controller for users distribution in terms of percent for 9 scenarios as Percent Executions-PerUser-Unchecked.

I have assigned users per scenario using the below calculation.
[image]

From the above calculation,30 users distributed among 9 scenarios as below. 
[image]

So,1)I am not sure is users distribution converted exactly as original design? Did I achieve? If not how do I achieve  this?

```
 2)Should I Uncheck or Check PercentExecutions-PerUser

 3)Should I choose Uncheck or Check TotalExecutions-PerUser
```

Please advise!

See the below screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below link gave me the clarification

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability